# sonicwall-multiple IP's for same interface

Tags: networking, firewall, ip, local-area-network, sonicwall

I am new to sonicwall.Is there any way to add multiple ip's to a sonicwall interface ?.
In my lab there are two local networks connected to same switch (networks are overlapped). I need to communicate these network through the same sonicwall interface( other interfaces are used for other different networks)
A sample diagram of my network follows.
[image: A sample diagram of my network]

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sub-interface on your LAN interface (X0, usually) and use VLAN tagging to separate the traffic. In Network > Interfaces there is a "Add Interface" button.

Comment: I tried that.But it need a manageable switch too ?

Comment: Yes, you need to be able to do VLANs on your switch. Doing this set up, we had 4 different networks all configured on X0 for a particular project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, it's not intuitive though.  Also, you should have been able to find the documentation through Google?

Here's the document: http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/supporting_multiple_firewalled_subnets_on_sonicos_enhanced.pdf

> Example #1 Default NAT Mode with secondary subnet
>
> 1. Create Static ARP entry for the gateway address of secondary subnet on the LAN interface
> 2. Create address object for secondary subnet
> 3. Add static route for the secondary subnet

Comment: i need to use this secondary subnet for vpn tunnel. Is that possible ?

Comment: Try it and see?  Sounds like a rather silly setup anyway.  Plus I've already done too much of your work for you.